# Why does the buffer overflow in this code behave different from what I expect?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, output, buffer

I have this Program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {
    char *buffer1 = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *buffer2 = malloc(sizeof(char));

    strcpy(buffer2, "AA");

    printf("before: buffer1 %s\n", buffer1);
    printf("before: buffer2 %s\n", buffer2);

    printf("address, buffer1 %p\n", &buffer1);
    printf("address, buffer2 %p\n", &buffer2);

    strcpy(buffer1, "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");

    printf("after: buffer1 %s\n", buffer1);
    printf("after: buffer2 %s\n", buffer2);
}
```

Which prints:

```
before: buffer1 
before: buffer2 AA
address, buffer1 0x7ffc700460d8
address, buffer2 0x7ffc700460d0
after: buffer1 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
after: buffer2 B
```

#### What I expect this code to do:

- As a char is 8 bits long, i expect that both buffers have the size of 1 byte/8 bits.
- One ASCII char is 7 bits long, i expect that two characters fit into each buffer.
- As I allocate two buffers of one byte directly after each other, i expect that they are directly next to each other in the memory. Therefore, i expect that the difference between each address is 1 (since the memory is addressed by byte?), and not 8 as my little program has printed.
- As they are directly next to each other in the memory, i expect buffer 2 to be overflown with `BB` when I do `strcpy(buffer1, BBBB);` as the first `BB` are written to `buffer1` and the rest overflows to `buffer2`. Therefore, i'd expect that `strcpy(buffer1, "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");` produces:

  - an buffer overflow in `buffer2`, so  that it has the value `BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB` or so.

    - How I calculated that: the amonut of `B` which have been strcpy'd - 4 `B`'s for both buffers.
  - an segmentation fault. I have only allocated 2 bytes (since the size of `buffer1` and `buffer2` are together 2 bytes). Since `BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB` doesn't fit into neither `buffer1` nor `buffer2` (because both are already filled), that would be overflown to the next memory buffer after `buffer2`. And because i have not allocated that, i'd expect an segmentation fault.

**Therefore, I want to ask: Why does my program act different than my expectations? Where did I misunderstand things?**

*I have a x86_64 architecture and the above program is compiled with `gcc version 6.3.1 20170306 (GCC)`*

#### What I do not ask for:

- I know that `strcpy` is not bound checking and the usage is intentional. I want to investiage buffer overflows and such. Therefore, please don't write an answer/comment saying that i should use a different method as `strcpy`.

Comment: Most of your expectations are wrong.  If you really want to do this, try `char buffer[1]` and `char buffer2[1]`.  Calling `malloc` changes everything.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you're doing your math (and I don't mean to insult your intelligence), but 7 + 7 = 14, and 14 is greater than 8.  (But no computer uses 7-bit ASCII any more.  For all intents and purposes, a character is 8 bits, unless you're using Unicode.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I'm not sure what exactly you're refering to. I calculated like that: one buffer is 2^8 big and 2^8 = 2^7 + 2^7. Did you mean that?  But i don't understand what you mean with "14 is greater than 8"

Comment: @SinanÜnür Can you please be constructive? Your comment is not at all helpful.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1. You allocate space for a single `char` then you claim that its size is 2^8. It is hard to take that statement seriously. Similarly for your statement "*i don't understand what you mean with '14 is greater than 8'*.

Comment: the 8 in 2^8 was meant as bits. 8 bits are one byte. I don't see where my error is. (Sorry, i'm a bit new in this Bit/Byte area).

Comment: Note: technically, this is not a buffer overflow, but a *heap corruption*. And the number of bits/character is not relevant, the smallest addressable unit is always a char.

Comment: You can't fit two 7-bit values into an 8-bit space.  You need at least 14 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - As a char is 8 bits long, ...

This is correct for the stated architecture and operating system.  (The C standard allows `char` to be *more* than 8 bits long, but this is very rare nowadays; the only example I know of is the [TMS320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TMS320) family of DSPs, where `char` may be 16 bits. It's not allowed to be smaller.)

Note that `sizeof(char) == 1` **by definition** and therefore it is generally considered bad style to write `sizeof(char)` or `foo * sizeof(char)` in your code.

> ... i expect that both buffers have the size of 1 byte/8 bits.

This is also correct (but see below).

> - One ASCII char is 7 bits long, i expect that two characters fit into each buffer.

This is not correct, for two reasons.  First, nobody uses 7-bit ASCII anymore.  Each character is in fact *eight* bits long.  Second, two seven-bit characters *do not* fit into one eight-bit buffer.  I see that there is some confusion on this point in the comments on the question, so let me attempt to explain further: Seven bits can represent 2<sup>7</sup> different values, just enough room for the 128 different characters defined by the original ASCII standard.  Two seven-bit characters, together, can have 128 * 128 = 16384 = 2<sup>14</sup> different values; that requires 14 bits to represent, and will not fit into eight bits.  You seem to have thought it was only 2 * 128 = 2<sup>8</sup>, which would fit into eight bits, but that's not right; it would mean that once you saw the first character, there were only *two* possibilities for the second character, not 128.

> - As I allocate two buffers of one byte directly after each other, i expect that they are directly next to each other in the memory. Therefore, i expect that the difference between each address is 1 (since the memory is addressed by byte?), and not 8 as my little program has printed.

As you have observed for yourself, your expectations are incorrect.

`malloc` is not required to put consecutive allocations next to each other; in fact, "are these allocations next to each other" may not be a meaningful question.  The C standard goes out of its way to *avoid* requiring there to be *any* meaningful comparison between two pointers that don't point into the same array.

Now, you are working on a system with a "flat address space", so it *is* meaningful to compare pointers from successive allocations (provided you do it in your own brain, not with code) and there is a logical explanation for the gap between the allocations, but first I have to point out that you printed the wrong addresses:

```
printf("address, buffer1 %p\n", &buffer1);
printf("address, buffer2 %p\n", &buffer2);
```

This prints the addresses of the *pointer variables*, not the addresses of the *buffers*.  You should have written

```
printf("address, buffer1 %p\n", (void *)buffer1);
printf("address, buffer2 %p\n", (void *)buffer2);
```

(The cast to `void *` is required because `printf` takes a variable argument list.)  If you had written that you would have seen output similar to

```
address, buffer1 0x55583d9bb010
address, buffer2 0x55583d9bb030
```

and the important thing to notice is that these allocations differ by *sixteen* bytes, and not only that, they're both evenly divisible by 16.

`malloc` is required to produce buffers that are *aligned* as required for *any* type, even if you can't fit a value of that type into the allocation.  An address is aligned to some number of bytes if it's evenly divisible by that number.  On your system, the maximum alignment requirement is 16; you can confirm this by running this program...

```
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { printf("%zu\n", alignof(max_align_t)); return 0; }
```

So that means all addresses returned by `malloc` must be evenly divisible by 16. Therefore, when you ask `malloc` for two one-byte buffers, it has to leave a fifteen-byte gap between them.  This *does not* mean that `malloc` rounded the size up; the C standard specifically forbids you to access the bytes in the gap.  (I'm not aware of any modern, commercial CPUs that can enforce that prohibition, but debugging tools like [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org) will, and there have been experimental CPU designs that can do it.  Also, often the space immediately before or after a `malloc` block contains data used internally by the `malloc` implementation, which you must not tamper with.)

There's a similar gap after the second allocation.

> - As they are directly next to each other in the memory, i expect buffer 2 to be overflown with `BB` when I do `strcpy(buffer1, BBBB);` as the first `BB` are written to `buffer1` and the rest overflows to `buffer2`.

As previously discussed, they are not directly next to each other in memory, and each B takes up *eight* bits.  One B is written to your first allocation, the next 15 to the gap between the two allocations, the 16th to the second allocation, 15 more after that to the gap *after* the second allocation, and the final one B and one NUL to the space beyond.

> I have only allocated 2 bytes (since the size of `buffer1` and `buffer2` are together 2 bytes). Since `BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB` doesn't fit into neither `buffer1` nor `buffer2` (because both are already filled), that would be overflown to the next memory buffer after `buffer2`. And because i have not allocated that, i'd expect an segmentation fault.

We've already discussed why your calculations were incorrect, but you *did* write all the way past the end of the gap after the second allocation and into the "space beyond", so why no segfault?  This is because, at the level of operating system primitives, memory is allocated to applications in units called "[pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory))", which are larger than the amount of memory you asked for.  The CPU can only detect a buffer overrun and trigger a segmentation fault if the overrun crosses a page boundary.  You just didn't go far enough.  I experimented with your program on my computer, which is very similar, and I need to write *132 kilobytes* (a kilobyte is 1024 bytes) (some people say that that's supposed to be called a kibibyte; they are wrong) beyond the end of buffer1 to get a segfault.  Pages on my computer are only 4 kilobytes each, but `malloc` asks the OS for memory in even larger chunks because system calls are expensive.

Not getting a prompt segfault *does not* mean you are safe; there is an excellent chance you clobbered `malloc`'s internal data, or another allocation somewhere in the "space beyond".  If I take your original program and add a call to `free(buffer1)` at the end, it crashes in there.

Answer (score 3):

First, please read [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

---

Now focus on how you allocating memory.

[How much memory does malloc(1) allocate?](http://prog21.dadgum.com/179.html)

> 8 bytes of overhead are added to our need for a single byte, and the
>   total is smaller than the minimum of 32, so that's our answer:
>   malloc(1) allocates 32 bytes.

which makes your basis soft.

<sub>Note: `malloc(1)` allocates 32 bytes That may be true for the implemenation discussed on that link, but it is extremely implementation-dependent and will be differ.</sub>

---

On the other hand, if you had done:

```
char buffer1[1], buffer2[1];
```

instead of dynamically allocating memory, you would see different results. For example, in my system:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out // with malloc
before: buffer1 
before: buffer2 AA
address, buffer1 0x7fff5ecb6bd8
address, buffer2 0x7fff5ecb6bd0
after: buffer1 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
after: buffer2 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c // no malloc
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
Abort trap: 6
```

---

Tip: The size has not officially been rounded up; accessing bytes beyond the requested size has **Undefined Behavior**. (If it were officially rounded up, this would have implementation-defined behavior.)

Comment: *malloc(1) allocates 32 bytes* That may be true for the implemenation discussed on that link, but it is **extremely** implementation-dependent and will differ for other implementations.

Comment: @AndrewHenle correct, updated by pasting your comment, hope you are okay with that!

Comment: Maybe even more important to point out that the size has _not_ officially been rounded up; accessing bytes beyond the requested size has undefined behavior.  (If it were officially rounded up, this would have implementation-defined behavior.)

Comment: @zwol correct! I remember arguing hard with a Swiss guy about it when I was in my 2nd year of university! By the way, I now saw your answer, very good.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` does not guarantee location in memory. You cannot be sure even with back to back calls that the memory space will be contiguous. In addition, `malloc` often allocates more space than necessary. A segfault could well occur with your code, but is not guaranteed.

`printf` with the `%s` specifier prints characters from the pointer until a `NUL` (ASCII 0) character is encountered.

Remember, buffer overflow is undefined behavior, which means just that: you do not know exactly what will happen.